# how to set time for reading an input using getline in c++?

Tags: c++

i am trying to develop a program that it waits for particular period of time for input and comes out after some time in c++ ,like we do in atm machine .
can anyone try to help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 string name;
 cout << "Enter your name: ";
 int endTime= 5;
 int i=0;
// cout<<endTime<<endl; 
 while(i < endTime)
 {
   getline(cin, name);
    i++;
    endTime--;
   if( i > endTime && (name.empty()))

     break;
 }

 cout << "NO NAME ENTERED!!" << endl;
```

Comment: I certainly hope ATM machines don't just randomly have calls to `sleep()`.

Comment: Not in standard C++. The closest you can get would still be reading input after the timeout occurs, even if your timeout logic executes and it throws away that read value.

Comment: @InduSekharReddy state your OS cause there are OS specific ways to solve this. e.g. in MSDOS you can read character by character but check the keyboard buffer before you read the character enabling you to do other things while the user was typing.

Comment: @claptrap You think ATMs (or anything really) are still using MS-DOS? The last version was released in the year 2000, and I don't think there are security updates forthcoming, so let's hope not!

Comment: @CodyGray i hope not although after hearing stories from a guy who worked for a larger German bank I would not be that surprised ^_^  it was more of an example of an OS specific way of solving his issue.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that getline() is a blocking call, and won't return until someone inputs something.

What you could do is to research threading - have two different threads, one of which has the sole responsibility to watch time, and if the time has passed, then you send a signal to kill the other thread.

You are limited a lot by the input method that you showed here.

Comment: Well, you are correct - nothing standard, which is why I mentioned that the input method is very limiting.

Comment: i tried to use alarm() and clock() functions in my program but it does not work ..

Comment: Alarm() and clock() won't help here. The problem is that getline() will block anything else from happening until it receives the input it is waiting for. Nothing else can happen.

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 string name;
 cout<<"enter your name"<<endl;
 alarm(3);
 getline(cin,name);
} i tried these program its waiting for 3 seconds and exiting from command prompt but i need to call another function without exiting